# Typescript typeof not detecting methods from class

Tags: typescript

So I have this class

```
declare class Record<Entries extends Dict = Dict, Key extends keyof Entries = keyof Entries, FieldLookup extends Dict<keyof Entries, number> = Dict<keyof Entries, number>> {
    keys: Key[];
    length: number;
    private readonly _fields;
    private readonly _fieldLookup;

    constructor(keys: Key[], fields: any[], fieldLookup?: FieldLookup);

    forEach(visitor: Visitor<Entries, Key>): void;
    map<Value>(visitor: MapVisitor<Value, Entries, Key>): Value[];
    entries(): IterableIterator<[string, any]>;
    values(): IterableIterator<Object>;
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<Object>;
    toObject(): Entries;
    get<K extends keyof Entries = keyof Entries>(key: K): Entries[K];
    get(n: number): any;
    has(key: Key | string | number): boolean;
}
```

It's used in this function:

```
export function toObjects(
    records: typeof neo4j.Record[],
    converters: Converters
) {
    const recordValues = records.map(record => {
        const out: string[] = []
        record.forEach((val: {}) => out.push(itemIntToString(val, converters)))
        return out
    })
    return recordValues
}
```

Even if `forEach` method seems well defined I get the error `'Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'typeof Record'`

Also it's worth noticing I have several similar errors among the code with the use of `typeof`

Any idea where it can come from ? I'm puzzled here.

EDIT:
neo4j here is

```
declare const forExport: {
  Record: typeof Record,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `typeof` instead of giving your variable the type of the object directly? (`records: neo4j.Record[]`)

Comment: What's `neo4j`? Could you make this a [mre] that immediately demonstrates your issue when others paste it directly into their own IDEs?

Comment: all the needed  code is here , it's a theoretical case, someone knowing typescript well should be able to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

consider removing the "typeof" before Record when defining the neo4j type. Typescript considers classes as valid types

```typescript
declare const forExport: {
    Record: Record
}
```

Comment: what's the issue/explaination ? why typeof wouldn't work ? it's from the official github lib, I mean pushed something that's working they didn't code random stuff

Comment: Using the class definition as a type would mean an instance of the class, but typeof Class definition would mean the static prototype of the class, so you would only have access to static variables and methods